# Finding the most profitable permutations of long/short pairs in Python - an optimization problem?

Tags: python, pandas, optimization, pulp

I have daily profit data and I'm trying to find the best combinations of two assets that will return the highest profit. I need to purchase one asset long and short the other and find the best performing pair over a time window.

I can accomplish this by searching through all the permutations, but it's extremely slow. (no surprise there) I *think* this might be the type of problem suited for linear optimization with a library like PuLP.

Here's a sample of solving the problem exhaustively. I'm intentionally keeping the data simple, but I have 1000 assets that I need to search through. It took about 45 minutes to finish with the inefficient, manual approach I outline below.

*Note: Because going long "Alpha" and short "Bravo" is different than going long "Bravo" and going short "Alpha", I'm using permutations, not combinations.*

Edit: in case some aren't familiar with *longing* and *shorting*, I'm trying to pair the highest profit with the lowest profit (with a *short*, I make more profit the more negative the value is)

The logic would read something like this:

> For all the permutations of nodes, add the node one profit to the inverse of the node two profit to get a total profit. Find the pair that has the highest total profit.

Here's my very inefficient (but working) implementation:

```
# Sample data
profits = [
    ('2019-11-18', 'Alpha', -79.629698),
    ('2019-11-19', 'Alpha', -17.452517),
    ('2019-11-20', 'Alpha', -19.069558),
    ('2019-11-21', 'Alpha', -66.061564),
    ('2019-11-18', 'Bravo', -87.698670),
    ('2019-11-19', 'Bravo', -73.812616),
    ('2019-11-20', 'Bravo', 198.513246),
    ('2019-11-21', 'Bravo', -69.579466),
    ('2019-11-18', 'Charlie', 66.302287),
    ('2019-11-19', 'Charlie', -16.132065),
    ('2019-11-20', 'Charlie', -123.735898),
    ('2019-11-21', 'Charlie', -30.046416),
    ('2019-11-18', 'Delta', -131.682322),
    ('2019-11-19', 'Delta', 13.296473),
    ('2019-11-20', 'Delta', 23.595053),
    ('2019-11-21', 'Delta', 14.103027),
]

profits_df = pd.DataFrame(profits, columns=('Date','Node','Profit')).sort_values('Date')
```

`profits_df` looks like this:

```
+----+------------+---------+-------------+
|    |    Date    |  Node   |   Profit    |
+----+------------+---------+-------------+
|  0 | 2019-11-18 | Alpha   | -79.629698  |
|  4 | 2019-11-18 | Bravo   | -87.698670  |
|  8 | 2019-11-18 | Charlie | 66.302287   |
| 12 | 2019-11-18 | Delta   | -131.682322 |
|  1 | 2019-11-19 | Alpha   | -17.452517  |
+----+------------+---------+-------------+
```

To solve the problem manually, I can do this:

```
date_dfs = []

# I needed a way to take my rows and combine them pairwise, this
# is kind of gross but it does work

for date, date_df in profits_df.groupby('Date'):
    tuples = [tuple(x) for x in date_df[['Node', 'Profit']].to_numpy()]
    pp = list(itertools.permutations(tuples, 2))
    flat_pp = [[p[0][0], p[0][1], p[1][0], p[1][1]] for p in pp]
    df = pd.DataFrame(flat_cc, columns=['Long', 'LP', 'Short', 'SP'])
    date_dfs.append(df)

result_df = pd.concat(daily_dfs)
result_df['Pair'] = result_df['Long'] + '/' + result_df['Short']
result_df['Profit'] = result_df['LP'] + result_df['SP'].multiply(-1)

result_df.groupby('Pair')['Profit'].sum().sort_values(ascending=False)
```

By computing the profits for all permutations each day then summing them up, I get this result:

```
+-----------------------------+
|            Pair             |
+-----------------------------+
| Bravo/Alpha      149.635831 |
| Delta/Alpha      101.525568 |
| Charlie/Alpha     78.601245 |
| Bravo/Charlie     71.034586 |
| Bravo/Delta       48.110263 |
| Delta/Charlie     22.924323 |
| Charlie/Delta    -22.924323 |
| Delta/Bravo      -48.110263 |
| Charlie/Bravo    -71.034586 |
| Alpha/Charlie    -78.601245 |
| Alpha/Delta     -101.525568 |
| Alpha/Bravo     -149.635831 |
+-----------------------------+
```

I'm certain there is a more efficient way to go about this. I don't understand the intricacies of optimization, but I know *of* it enough to know it's a possible solution. I don't understand the difference between linear optimization and non-linear, so I apologize if I'm getting the nomenclature wrong.

Can anyone suggest an approach I should try?

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding the problem, but why do you need the permutations? Can't you just find the most positive value to be your long and then find the most negative value to be your short? If you just want the best permutations, shouldn't this always suffice? Its linear to find the max and the min, rather than the factorial scaling to generate all the permutations.

Comment: In trying to keep my problem statement simple, I omitted the fact that in this domain (energy trading), the pairs are traded for a specific hour on a specific day. Prices fluctuate wildly throughout the hours/days, and I'm trying to come up with the best pairings over a 60 day period. I did experiment with keeping only the best pairings each day, but the poor pairings are needed to get a more accurate idea of overall performance. Your question is a good one, and I appreciate you asking. (I often make problems more complicated than necessary)

Answer (score 2):

Summary of what I did:

1. create a dictionary from the profits list
2. run the permutations for each key,value pair
3. iterate through each pair to get a combination of the names and amounts separately.
4. Sort the container list by name, groupby by name, sum the amounts for each groupby, and load final result into a dictionary.
5. Read the dictionary into a dataframe and sort values by Profit in descending order.

I believe all the processing should be done before it comes into the dataframe, and you should get significant speed up:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import permutations, groupby

d = defaultdict(list)
for k, v,s in profits:
    d[k].append((v,s))

container = []
for k,v in d.items():
    l = (permutations(v,2))
#here I combine the names and the amounts separately into A and B
    for i,j in l:
        A = i[0]+'_'+j[0]
        B = i[-1]+(j[-1]*-1)
        container.append([A,B])

#here I sort the list, then groupby (groupby wont work if you don't sort first)
container = sorted(container, key=itemgetter(0,1))

sam = dict()
for name, amount in groupby(container,key=itemgetter(0)):
    sam[name] = sum(i[-1] for i in amount)

outcome = pd.DataFrame
          .from_dict(sam,
                     orient='index',
                     columns=['Profit'])
          .sort_values(by='Profit',
                       ascending=False)

             Profit
Bravo_Alpha 149.635831
Delta_Alpha 101.525568
Charlie_Alpha   78.601245
Bravo_Charlie   71.034586
Bravo_Delta 48.110263
Delta_Charlie   22.924323
Charlie_Delta   -22.924323
Delta_Bravo -48.110263
Charlie_Bravo   -71.034586
Alpha_Charlie   -78.601245
Alpha_Delta -101.525568
Alpha_Bravo -149.635831
```

when I ran it on my PC it was 1.24ms, while urs came in at 14.1ms. Hopefully, someone can produce something much faster.

**UPDATE:**

All I did for the first one was unnecessary. There is no need for permutation - the multiplier is -1. Meaning all we need to do is get the sum for each name, pair the names (with no repeats), multiply one of the values by -1 and add to another, then when we have the lump sum for a pair, multiply by -1 again to get the reverse. I got a speed of about 18.6μs, which shoots up to 273μs once pandas is introduced. That's some significant speed up. Most of the compute was reading the data into pandas. Here goes:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import combinations, chain
import pandas as pd

def optimizer(profits):

    nw = defaultdict(list)
    content = dict()

    [nw[node].append((profit)) for dat,node,profit in profits]

    #sum the total for each key
    B = {key : sum(value) for key ,value in nw.items()}

    #multiply the value of the second item in the tuple by -1
    #add that to the value of the first item in the tuple
    #pair the result back to the tuple and form a dict
    sumr = {(first,last):sum((B[first],B[last]*-1))
                              for first,last 
                              in combinations(B.keys(),2)}

    #reverse the positions in the tuple for each key
    #multiply the value by -1 and pair to form a dict
    rev = {tuple(reversed(k)): v*-1 
           for k,v in sumr.items()}

    #join the two dictionaries into one
    #sort in descending order
    #and create a dictionary
    result = dict(sorted(chain(sumr.items(),
                               rev.items()
                               ),
                  key = itemgetter(-1),
                  reverse=True
                  ))

    #load into pandas
    #trying to reduce the compute time here by reducing pandas workload
    return pd.DataFrame(list(result.values()),
                        index = list(result.keys()),
                        )
```

I would probably delay reading into the dataframe till it is unavoidable. I'd love to know what the actual speed was when you run it on your end.

Comment: Thank you for this - it's cleaner than what I posted. I ran it on my data set and it still took 74 minutes to complete, almost all of that time was spent creating the permutations. (for simplicity, I did not mention that my data is broken down by hour and day, so there are 24 runs at ~3 min each to process all the data) Hopefully there is a way to do this with an optimizer!

Comment: Updated my solution. Let me know how it goes. All of that optimization worry must be fun for you.

Comment: It turns out that I don't need to keep separate DataFrames for each hour/day and concat them, that is very slow. I found a very, fast solution that calculates a Numpy matrix for each node pair then just adds them to a running matrix. It's not until the end that I turn it into a DataFrame. (thanks to your idea on that) I got the runtime down from 47 minutes to 13 seconds, which is not an optimization solution but will work well for my needs. I'll post it here once I clean it up.

Comment: glad to know it worked. did you try my solution and see if u get the same results?

Comment: Yes, it was incredibly fast compared to all the original implementations and the concept you shared got me to an implementation that works for my needs. Thank you for taking the time to do that for me.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't *technically* the answer because it's not solved using optimization techniques, but hopefully someone might find it useful.

From testing, it's the construction and concatenation of the DataFrames that's the slow part. It's trivially fast to use Numpy to create a matrix of pair prices:

```
arr = df['profit'].values + df['profit'].multiply(-1).values[:, None]
```

Produces this matrix of each node multiplied by each node:

```
+---+-------------+------------+------------+------------+
|   | 0           | 1          | 2          | 3          |
+---+-------------+------------+------------+------------+
| 0 | 0.000000    | 149.635831 | 78.598163  | 101.525670 |
+---+-------------+------------+------------+------------+
| 1 | -149.635831 | 0.000000   | -71.037668 | -48.110161 |
+---+-------------+------------+------------+------------+
| 2 | -78.598163  | 71.037668  | 0.000000   | 22.927507  |
+---+-------------+------------+------------+------------+
| 3 | -101.525670 | 48.110161  | -22.927507 | 0.000000   |
+---+-------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

If you construct an empty numpy array with dimensions of `number of nodes` * `number of nodes`, then you can simply add the daily array to the totals array:

```
total_arr = np.zeros((4, 4))

# Do this for each day
arr = df['profit'].values + df['profit'].multiply(-1).values[:, None]

total_arr += arr
```

Once you have that, you need to do some Pandas voodoo to assign the node names to the matrix and unstack the matrix into individual long/short/profit rows.

My original (exhaustive) search took 47 minutes with 60 days of data. It's down to 13 seconds now.

Full working example:

```
profits = [
    {'date':'2019-11-18', 'node':'A', 'profit': -79.629698},
    {'date':'2019-11-19', 'node':'A', 'profit': -17.452517},
    {'date':'2019-11-20', 'node':'A', 'profit': -19.069558},
    {'date':'2019-11-21', 'node':'A', 'profit': -66.061564},
    {'date':'2019-11-18', 'node':'B', 'profit': -87.698670},
    {'date':'2019-11-19', 'node':'B', 'profit': -73.812616},
    {'date':'2019-11-20', 'node':'B', 'profit': 198.513246},
    {'date':'2019-11-21', 'node':'B', 'profit': -69.579466},
    {'date':'2019-11-18', 'node':'C', 'profit': 66.3022870},
    {'date':'2019-11-19', 'node':'C', 'profit': -16.132065},
    {'date':'2019-11-20', 'node':'C', 'profit': -123.73898},
    {'date':'2019-11-21', 'node':'C', 'profit': -30.046416},
    {'date':'2019-11-18', 'node':'D', 'profit': -131.68222},
    {'date':'2019-11-19', 'node':'D', 'profit': 13.2964730},
    {'date':'2019-11-20', 'node':'D', 'profit': 23.5950530},
    {'date':'2019-11-21', 'node':'D', 'profit': 14.1030270},
]

# Initialize a Numpy array of node_length * node_length dimension
profits_df = pd.DataFrame(profits)
nodes = profits_df['node'].unique()
total_arr = np.zeros((len(nodes), len(nodes)))

# For each date, calculate the pairs profit matrix and add it to the total
for date, date_df in profits_df.groupby('date'):
    df = date_df[['node', 'profit']].reset_index()
    arr = df['profit'].values + df['profit'].multiply(-1).values[:, None]
    total_arr += arr

# This will label each column and row
nodes_series = pd.Series(nodes, name='node')
perms_df = pd.concat((nodes_series, pd.DataFrame(total_arr, columns=nodes_series)), axis=1)

# This collapses our matrix back to long, short, and profit rows with the proper column names
perms_df = perms_df.set_index('node').unstack().to_frame(name='profit').reset_index()
perms_df = perms_df.rename(columns={'level_0': 'long', 'node': 'short'})

# Get rid of long/short pairs where the nodes are the same (not technically necessary)
perms_df = perms_df[perms_df['long'] != perms_df['short']]

# Let's see our profit
perms_df.sort_values('profit', ascending=False)
```

Result:

```
+----+------+-------+-------------+
|    | long | short | profit      |
+----+------+-------+-------------+
| 4  | B    | A     | 149.635831  |
+----+------+-------+-------------+
| 12 | D    | A     | 101.525670  |
+----+------+-------+-------------+
| 8  | C    | A     | 78.598163   |
+----+------+-------+-------------+
| 6  | B    | C     | 71.037668   |
+----+------+-------+-------------+
| 7  | B    | D     | 48.110161   |
+----+------+-------+-------------+
| 14 | D    | C     | 22.927507   |
+----+------+-------+-------------+
| 11 | C    | D     | -22.927507  |
+----+------+-------+-------------+
| 13 | D    | B     | -48.110161  |
+----+------+-------+-------------+
| 9  | C    | B     | -71.037668  |
+----+------+-------+-------------+
| 2  | A    | C     | -78.598163  |
+----+------+-------+-------------+
| 3  | A    | D     | -101.525670 |
+----+------+-------+-------------+
| 1  | A    | B     | -149.635831 |
+----+------+-------+-------------+
```

Thanks to sammywemmy for helping me organize the problem and come up with something useful.